# Как увеличить размер слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
// Can also be used with $(document).ready()
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
```

```css
/*Slider*/
ul{
    list-style: none;
}


/*
.slider{
    height: 445px;
    background: #40c7ba;
}
*/

.kofta{
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: 65px;
}

.flexslider {
  background: #40c7ba;
  height: 445px;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -o-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.flexslider .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  height: auto;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
.flex-viewport {
  max-height: 2000px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.loading .flex-viewport {
  max-height: 300px;
}
.carousel li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.flex-direction-nav {
  *height: 0;
}
.flex-direction-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -20px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    left: -50px;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    right: -50px;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  opacity: 0.7;
  right: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
  opacity: 0!important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: default;
  z-index: -1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}
.flex-pauseplay a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.flex-pauseplay a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a.flex-play:before {
}
.flex-control-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.flex-control-paging li a {
  position: relative;
  top: -68px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  background: 
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.flex-control-paging li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #77d3cb;
  cursor: default;
}
.flex-control-thumbs {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
 * RESPONSIVE
 * ====================================================================================================================*/
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Aditii</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script src="slider.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider">
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img class="kofta" src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/16/4c5204c7ef78a0f60adbba872f31239b-full.png">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Не могу понять почему java выдаёт ошибку

но проблема заключается в этом [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой слайдер обрезает часть футболки, как сделать так что бы он её не обрезал?

Что бы получалось как-то так

Answer (score 0):

```
.flex-viewport {
  height: 445px; /*заменив max-height: 2000px; на этот*/
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Сам решил эту проблему